# How can I integrate Oracle's row level security with MyBatis?

Tags: oracle, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc, mybatis

A project I am working on uses and Oracle database with row level security. I need to be able to invoke `call DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO('userId');` before I can execute any other SQL statements. I am trying to figure out a way to implement this within MyBatis. Several ideas that I had, but were unable to make work, include the following:

#### Attempt 1

```
<select id="selectIds" parameterType="string" resultType="Integer">
      call DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(#{userId});
    select id from FOO
</select>
```

However, you can't two statements within a single JDBC call and MyBatis doesn't have support for JDBC batch statements, or at least not that I could find.

#### Attempt 2

```
<select id="selectMessageIds" parameterType="string" resultType="Integer">
    <![CDATA[
        declare
           type ID_TYP is table of AGL_ID.ID_ID%type;
           ALL_IDS ID_TYP;
        begin
           DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(#{userId});
           select ID bulk collect
             into ALL_IDS
             from FOO
        end;
    ]]>
</select>
```

However, that is as far I got because I learned that you can't return data in a procedure, only in a function, so there was no way to return the data.

#### Attempt 3

I've considered just creating a simple MyBatis statement that will set the client information and it will need to be called before executing statements. This seems the most promising, however, we are using Spring and database connection pooling and I am concerned about race conditions. I want to ensure that the client information won't bleed over and affect other statements because the connections will not get closed, they will get reused.

#### Software/Framework Version Information

Oracle 10g
MyBatis 3.0.5
Spring 3.0.5

**Update**
Forgot to mention that I am also using MyBatis Spring 1.0.1

Comment: You can retrieve data from procedures as well, use out params.  Pass a bean with getters and setters, and the out param will be populated on the bean after the call to mybatis.

Comment: Mybatis certainly does support batch transactions.  When you open an SQL Session, specify ExecutorType.BATCH.  If your using guice (I recommend it)  use @Transactional(executor=Batch). Have you read the user guide?  http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf

Comment: I will try the out parameters route. I have read the guide, several times, as well as dug through a lot of the source code for MyBatis. From the user guide: "Configures the
default executor. SIMPLE executor does nothing special. REUSE executor reuses prepared statements. BATCH executor reuses statements and batches updates." And looking at the source code, it does have methods that call addBatch(), however they are only ever invoked by update() methods, not select() methods.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for transactions. You can create a `@Transactional` service (or DAO) base class that makes the DBMS_APPLICATION function call. All your other service classes could extend the base and call the necessary SQL.

In the base class, you want to make sure that you only call the DBMS_APPLICATION function once. To do this, use the `TransactionSynchronizationManager.hasResource()` and `bindResource()` methods to bind a boolean or similar marker value to the current TX. Check this value to determine if you need to make the function call or not.

If the function call exists only for a 'unit of work' in the DB, this should be all you need. If the call exists for the duration of the connection, the base class will need too clean up in a finally block somehow.

Rather than a base class, another possibility would be to use AOP and do the function call before method invocation and the clean up as finally advice. The key here would be to make sure that your interceptor is called after Spring's TransactionInterceptor (i.e. after the tx has started).

Answer (score 0):

One of the safest solution would be to have a specilaized [DatSourceUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html)

[1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html): http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html and override doGetConnection(DataSource dataSource) and setClientInfo on connection

Write your own abstraction over [SqlMapClientDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html) to pass client information.

Comment: I have considered something similar this. The issue is that I won't have the client information up front. I am coding to the DAO interface. Short of casting the object to SqlMapClientDaoSupport, I am not sure how to go about providing the information to the connection. A larger concern is that if the DAOs aren't wired correctly in Spring, they will be singletons. I am worried about race conditions, i.e., one thread sets the client information and then a different thread sets different information before the first was able to execute the query. So, I am trying to keep this in mind, as well.